What is 'Be this sunset soon forgotten'?
The line is from the song 'Sunset Soon Forgotten' by Iron & Wine.
Do you think it originally comes from sentences like 'Let this sunset be soon forgotten' or 'May this sunset be soon forgotten' or does this sentence have the acient subjunctive structure like this?

Be this sunset soon forgotten


I suggest editing this question to focus on a different example of this pattern. Poetry and song lyrics often use words in non-standard ways. There's a common meaning for this pattern, "[if] this sunset [were to] be soon forgotten," but looking at the lyrics, it doesn't seem to be what's intended in this song.

It's probably a conditional: see this question on English Language and Usage. There's the pattern "Be this sunset soon forgotten ... Be this sunset one for keeping ..."

It's generally may but here it means even if this sunset is soon forgotten, imo. Songs and poems are interpreted with opinions...

Does this answer your question? Why is "be" used instead of "is" in this sentence "Be he alive, or be he dead"?. Also this one: "be it my mother ...  be it my sisters...".

@StuartF Did you check the context? These comments seem to be in line with my knee-jerk guess before reading the lyrics, but they don't seem substantiated by them, other than perhaps by indirect suggestion.

It seems to be saying either this sunset is soon forgotten, or it'll be kept in the memory, so it's the use of "be" for enumerating a set of possibilities. The rest of the lyrics don't seem to particularly relate to the sunset, but that's poetry for you. (Questions about poetic techniques belong on Literature SE, but it seems to be using the contrasting "be..." as a way of introducing verses of the song.)

It (and the next usage in the song) reads like an imperative, as with "Be off with you!" Each usage describes the situation that needs to be forgotten (or remembered).

This is 19th c. hymnal diction, deliberately quaint to sound more "poetical". Compare: "Be this when day is past / Of all your thoughts the last".

First, let's talk about other similar patterns for which the meaning is clear. A medieval Irish poem has a familiar English translation starting "Be thou my vision, O Lord of my heart." In this case, it's a simple imperative. "Be the thing that fills my sight." The pronoun "thou" (old familiar version of "you") is thrown in mainly to fill out the poetic metre.
A similar one is the Robert Frost usage in the linked question: "No bird is singing now, and if there is, / be it my loss." This is also a sort of an imperative, standing for "let it be my loss," which is itself a sort of roundabout future tense, "it will be my loss."
Another usage would be a conditional. In the tale of Jack and the Beanstalk, the giant uses rhyming verse to announce that he smells a human: "Be he alive or be he dead, I'll grind his bones to make my bread." Here, "be" is used archaically where we would just use "is," and there is a conditional using an implied "if": "If he be alive [or dead], I'll grind his bones."  If this were the intent, then "Be this sunset soon forgotten" would be followed with some consequence. "If this sunset [were to] be soon forgotten... [then this would happen]."
But we don't find that. The song lyric is short enough to quote in full here:

Be this sunset soon forgotten
Your brothers left here shaved and crazy
We’ve learned to hide our bottles in the well
And what's worth keeping, sun still sinking
[Refrain]
Down and down
Once again
Down and down
Gone again
[Verse 2]
Be this sunset one for keeping
This June bug street sings low and lovely
Those Band-Aid children chased your dog away
She runs, returning, sun still sinking
[Refrain repeats]

You ask about "this sentence," but many of these lines are not sentences; we have a collection of sentence fragments. As is often the case in poetry, we are left to guess at the missing fragments, or even without creating a meaning, we "harvest" emotions that are triggered by the connotations that the words and phrases raise for us.
Overall, the tone and theme of the poem seems to be nostalgia for childhood memories and concern over their fleeting nature. The speaker recalls details, some of which are aesthetically pleasing ("low and lovely,") and some of which might have been less pleasant at the time: hiding the evidence of underage drinking might be a fond memory or a problematic one, and "your brothers left here shaved and crazy" could be a complicated story that we're not told, or could perhaps suggest that they grew up and left town, perhaps enlisting in the military (where their heads are shaved), or simply as adults who have to shave. Regardless, some parts of these memories are "worth keeping," and like sunsets, they both subside ("sinking," "down and down,") and persistently return ("once again").
This context doesn't fit a reading of the first line as an imperative. I don't think the author wants these sunsets to be forgotten. Furthermore, the start of the second verse suggests the memories should be kept. If it is to be a conditional, the rest of it is missing and left to the hearer's imagination. But this doesn't fit well either, because the point seems to be that these sunsets can not be soon forgotten. At the most adventurous, I might read it as the same as "Be thou my vision": an imperative telling the listener to "be" the sunset, to embody the cycle of fading and returning, to inhabit the persistent memories. But this does nothing to remove the same problems the other readings have.
Ultimately, while we can define some common uses for this pattern, this poem doesn't fit any of them well, and while it evokes a certain mood, the line in question doesn't communicate a single clear meaning.

Interesting, I can now see it as "Should [in the event that] this sunset be forgotten / remembered" with the next line in each case giving a reason, and then each 3rd and 4th line countering it.

@Andy Bonner I’m sorry for asking about the abstract example. Now, I understand that it’s difficult to figure out what it means exactly in sentences like lyrics, poems, and other ambiguous texts, even for native speakers. Thank you for bringing some ideas to the table. Though it is difficult for me to understand the author’s real intention, your explanation still helps me to get a multi-faceted understanding of this song.

@WeatherVane I like your interpretation. I think it makes sense in the context. Should I regard the original line as a sentence like ‘Let this sunset be soon forgotten’? You said it might read as an imperative, but I’m not familiar with this type of structure.

I originally proposed the imperative, but in my first comment under this answer reviewed that.

@WeatherVane Oh, I see. So, now your best bet is a conditional?

Please see the last paragraph of this answer. In lyrics, poetry and art, the creator may not have intended a definite clear meaning.

There's definitely a contrast between the two days. One with brothers shaved and crazy, the other with singing low and lovely.  So an argument could be made that the first day is one better forgotten. Let that day be forgotten.

@TimR I agree. It goes like this: 'let us forget the dark days when our brothers were drafted into the war and Prohibition was enacted, but let us remember the days when this June bug street sang low and lovely and naughty children chased dogs, but both will soon be forgotten.' That is "Sunset Soon Forgotten.

@TimR In your idea, is it a imperative or a subjunctive? I would like to know if it's possible.

Contemporary grammar says English no longer has a subjunctive and would treat that as an impersonal imperative. There's little practical difference between the impersonal imperative and the jussive subjunctive when, as here, there is a deliberate invocation of archaic forms.  As I mentioned in a comment, it's evocative of 19th c. hymnal diction, and even back then it was already an archaism.

@TimR I finally understood why you used a phrase like 'survival of the subjunctive' in the other post. I have indeed never seen such sentences in modern English except for this kind of old-fashioned lyric.

The subjunctive survives in set phrases like "Be it ever so humble, there's no place like home" and in constructions like "If I were king of the forest...".

@user189378 Well, this particular song is maybe the worst example for talking about this particular construction, since it might not be intending it at all, and is not in fact a sentence. But most of what you just said sounds right, aside from the last clause. Robert Frost's "be it my loss" is neither contemporary nor common; in many similar constructions, more helping verbs are called in like "May the Force be with you," and these are still echoes of older patterns. Meanwhile plain old "personal" imperative is always an option: "Be my valentine."
